# Pgfplots: raw gnuplot set datafile commentchars '#%'; How to escape '%'?

Tags: shell-escape

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots} 
\makeatletter
\def\Printdimensionless#1{\strip@pt \dimexpr #1\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{data_fem_0.dat}
id   delta      E_1        E_2        v_12       v_21       G_12     err         porosity  E_cs_1_norm  E_cs_2_norm
049  -0.48      2.6891     2.9098     0.33942    0.36728    1.1087   0.010752    0.914955  0.89481      0.968249
047  -0.46      0.014184   0.1251     -0.3269    -2.8832    0.71385  0.0011567   0.88558   0.00343525   0.0302982
\end{filecontents} % inserts '%' comment lines
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=0.1in,
  },
  scale only axis,
  width=\columnwidth-0.5in,
  domain=-0.482362:0.035276,
  xmin=-0.495, xmax=0.0352762,
]
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ymin=-0.9, ymax=4.9,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=poisson12, raw gnuplot]
      {set datafile commentschars '#%'; # <-- SEE HERE
        plot './data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'}
    ;
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ytick={0,0.5,1},
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=young1, raw gnuplot]
      {set datafile commentschars "#%";
        plot './data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'E_cs_1_norm'};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This returns following error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \pgfplots@gnuplotcode.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.33     ;

?
```

Looking into gnuplot file:

```
$ cat demo-expand-plot-width-expr.poisson12.gnuplot
set table "demo-expand-plot-width-expr.poisson12.table"; set format "%.5f"
set format "%.7e";;set datafile commentschars '##plot '< plotpointreduce -t 0.01 --width 308.865 --height 57.81621 --xrange -0.495 0.0352762 --yrange -0.9 4.9 --x-column delta --y-column v_12 data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'
```

shows that setting the commentschars was not correct. Apparently the `%` has to be escaped. `\%` is helpful but still errors are thrown.

```
$ cat demo-expand-plot-width-expr.poisson12.gnuplot
set table "demo-expand-plot-width-expr.poisson12.table"; set format "%.5f"
set format "%.7e";;set datafile commentschars '##\%'; plot './data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the result is as intended, but this will produce no error:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\makeatletter
\let\%\@percentchar
\edef\#{\string#}
\makeatother
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
    group size=1 by 2,
    vertical sep=0.1in,
  },
  scale only axis,
  width=\columnwidth-0.5in,
  domain=-0.482362:0.035276,
  xmin=-0.495, xmax=0.0352762,
]
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ymin=-0.9, ymax=4.9,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=poisson12, raw gnuplot]
      {set datafile commentschars '\#\%';
        plot './data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'v_12'}
    ;
\nextgroupplot[
  height=0.8in,
  ytick={0,0.5,1},
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
  \addplot
    gnuplot[id=young1, raw gnuplot]
      {set datafile commentschars "\#\%";
        plot './data_fem_0.dat' u 'delta':'E_cs_1_norm'};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. Yes, it does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer but a possible way to circumvent the problem.

Adjust the `datafile commentschars` in a gnuplot config file.

1. `$HOME/.gnuplot` (global)
2. `$PWD/.gnuplot` (per-directory) (requires commpile time option `+USE_CWDRC`
   This can be verified by running `$ gnuplot -e "show version long; show loadpath"`)